# Find and replace data in a MySql database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns in a MySQL database, both has data/time

I have many records, that has actual date/time in the column `sent_at` like `2012-05-04 16:07:14`

But the many records in the column `date_recieved_by_proxy` has null value like `00/00/0000 00:00`

How can I give a sql command to replace `date_recieved_by_proxy = 00/00/0000 00:00` records with the date of `sent_at` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update your_table
set date_recieved_by_proxy = sent_at 
where date_recieved_by_proxy = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Alternatively you can try

```
where date_recieved_by_proxy is null
```

depending on the data type of your `date_recieved_by_proxy` column and if it can be `null`